# How should I handle the camera based popups which asks for allow or deny options for mobile automation?

Tags: android, appium, webdriver-io

I want to handle these popups and allow whenever the test runs. What capabilities should I set that allows the test to run without interacting with these popups.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the way setting up the capabilities by
`autoGrantPermissions: true` is letting me to allow the popup.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest Android Testing Library, then there's `GrantPermissionRule` that you can use to grant the permissions.

You can use it like:

```
@Rule public GrantPermissionRule grantPermission = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
```